# How to calculate distance to comets using Skyfields?

Tags: python, astronomy, skyfield

I'm using [`skyfield`](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) to compute the relative distance of planets to Earth as a function of time (as described on the skyfield home page). It works great and now I'm trying to implement Earth=>comet distance (e.g. 67P/ Tchouri).

I've found at NASA JPL, a way to create Spice SPK files for comets ([here](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/x/spk.html)) but it produces `xsp` files that I cannot seem to read with the `load` command from `skyfield`.

Another possibility I considered is to use orbital information as suggested for `pyephem` (see [here](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/catalogs.html)) but I don't know how to read them in `Skyfield`.

I also saw that comets were on the roadmap for `skyfield` coding sprint so that's maybe my answer but if you know a way to make it work with the current version that would be very helpful.

Comment: I get a 404 Not Found when I attempt to follow the URL http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/x/spk.html that you shared — could you double-check and see if you pasted it correctly?

Comment: The website seems down temporary but the URL is correct. I uploaded the file that I got from this site here: https://github.com/facero/skyfield-comets

Comment: I understood that the file that I obtained from the Horizons Ephemeris System web interface was in a text format. I now downloaded a binary file from the telnet interface (the web page seems still down).  It seems that the `load` command in skyfield can not load just any .bsp file. Am I right ?   Loading my bsp file with the `load` command returns a `_io.BufferedReader` type object instead of a `skyfield.jpllib.SpiceKernel` when loading the de422.bsp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skyfield did gain support for comets! You can find the details here:

https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/kepler-orbits.html#comets

Adapting the code from the documentation, here is the distance to a comet from the Minor Planet Center database:

```
from skyfield.api import load
from skyfield.constants import GM_SUN_Pitjeva_2005_km3_s2 as GM_SUN
from skyfield.data import mpc

ts = load.timescale()

eph = load('de421.bsp')
sun, earth = eph['sun'], eph['earth']

with load.open(mpc.COMET_URL) as f:
    comets = mpc.load_comets_dataframe(f)
comets = comets.set_index('designation', drop=False)
row = comets.loc['1P/Halley']
comet = sun + mpc.comet_orbit(row, ts, GM_SUN)

t = ts.utc(2020, 10, 17)
ra, dec, distance = earth.at(t).observe(comet).radec()

print('Distance in AU:', distance.au)
```

I see the result:

```
Distance in AU: 35.22790002485247
```